# Setting JSON field to null using lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda, variable-assignment

I have a JSON that looks something like this:

```
"items": [
        "something": "",
        "something_2": "",
        "field_of_interest": {
          "blah": [
            {
              "placeholder": "1",
              "category": "random"
            },
            {
              "placeholder": "2",
              "category": "random",
              "field_to_null": {
                "something_here": "",
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
```

I am trying to set the "field_to_null" field to null. These JSON fields are all encapsulated into objects and I have an expression that looks like this:

```
 Items.Select(x => x.FieldOfInterest)
       .Select(y => y.Blah
       .Select(z => z.FieldToNull).ToList().ForEach(a => a = null));
```

But I get an error on the second `.Select`. Error found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0411?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0411)). `Items` is a List of `Items` objects and `Blah` is a List of `FieldOfInterest` objects. I am fairly new to C# and writing lambda linq expressions, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, Linq is really used for querying (hence the Q) and not for mutating objects. I personally hate the `ForEach` extension. Secondly, you have given us JSON but we have no idea what the C# classes are. What is `items`?

Comment: @DavidG I agree, but I am using this code to write tests and would be convenient if I can set fields to null and run tests on that. `Items` is a List of `Items` objects and `Blah` is a List of `FieldOfInterest` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linq general philisophy is not to mutate things, which explains why `ForEach` is not a Linq extension method, but a method on some collection types, like `List`.

Usually try to avoid using unpure lambdas in Linq operators.

You can use Linq to do mutation nevertheless, via projection, using the `Select` operator, and passing it a lambda that will return the mutated argument.
Here is the result.

```cs
Items
    .Select(i => 
    {
        i.FieldOfInterest.Blah = i.FieldOfInterest.Blah
            .Select(bi => 
            {
                bi.field_to_null = null;
                return bi;
            })
            .ToList() // Transform to the needed collection type
        return i;
    });
```

This is equivalent to:

```cs
foreach(var i in Items)
{
    foreach(var bi in i.field_of_interest.Blah)
    {
        bi.field_to_null = null;
    }
}
```

The Non-Linq approach is obvioulsly more readable.